# A better alternative to [unauthorizedaccessexcepti] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

There are 71 questions tagged with [unauthorizedaccessexcepti](/questions/tagged/unauthorizedaccessexcepti) and 130 questions tagged [unauthorized](/questions/tagged/unauthorized). Both tags lack wiki or summary, and both of them don't look very good. The first one doesn't fit into max tag length limitation, and the other one is not very descriptive, but at least is a full word. It might be better it there was just [unauthorized-access](/questions/tagged/unauthorized-access) tag. It would probably be even better though if it was possible to use [unauthorized-access-exception](/questions/tagged/unauthorized-access-exception) tag, but that seems to be too long for the 25 symbols max in tag names.

I guess they should be merged in some way. Just bringing this to everyone's attention. Again.

Comment: Both shouldn't exist. It should be [tag:unauthorizedaccessexception].

Comment: @ColeJohnson try it, I bet it won't work due to max 25 symbols in tag names.

Comment: *Neither* should exist at all.  `unauthorized` is a horrible tag...

Comment: I vote for [tag:unauthorized-access].

Comment: Agree with @Charles, `[unauthorized]` almost looks like a meta-tag. If questions are about unauthorized HTTP requests, the existing [`[http-status-code-401]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-401) tag would be a better fit.